# Why do I need to flush my I/O stream to get the correct result?

Tags: c, iostream

Why the code below does not work? I mean, it shows all kinds of weird characters on console output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char mybuffer[80];
int main()
{
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen ("example.txt","r+");
    if (pFile == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");

    else {
        fputs ("test",pFile);

        fgets (mybuffer,80,pFile);
        puts (mybuffer);
        fclose (pFile);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However, the code below works well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char mybuffer[80];
int main()
{
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen ("example.txt","r+");
    if (pFile == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");

    else {
        fputs ("test",pFile);
        fflush (pFile);    
        fgets (mybuffer,80,pFile);
        puts (mybuffer);
        fclose (pFile);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Why I need to flush the stream in order to get the correct result?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the standard says so (§7.19.5.3/5):

> When a file is opened with update mode
>   ('+' as the second or third character
>   in the above list of mode argument
>   values), both input and output may be
>   performed on the associated stream.
>   However, output shall not be directly
>   followed by input without an
>   intervening call to the fflush
>   function or to a file positioning
>   function (fseek, fsetpos, or rewind),
>   and input shall not be directly
>   followed by output without an
>   intervening call to a file positioning
>   function, unless the input operation
>   encounters end-of-file.

There is a reason for this: output and input are normally buffered separately. When there's a flush or seek, it synchronizes the buffers with the file, but otherwise it can let them get out of synch. This genarally improves performance (e.g. when you do a read, it doesn't have to check whether the position you're reading from has been written since the data was read into the buffer).

Comment: @Lee: Simple, you read it from the point where you left off writing, you need to seek back to the beginning for that to work.

Comment: @Lee:because the "Test" that you wrote hasn't been read into the read buffer. A probable scenario is that when you open the file, it attempts to fill the read buffer. Since the file is empty, it sets a flag to say no input is available. Until you do a flush or seek, it's going to remain marked that way, so all attempts at reading will fail.

Answer (score 7):

When using a file with a read/write mode you must call fseek/fflush before different i/o operations.

See this answer on [why fseek or fflush is always required...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713819/why-fseek-or-fflush-is-always-required-between-reading-and-writing-in-the-read-wr/1713868)

Comment: Thx; I should've search harder

Answer (score 2):

its because C file io works using a buffer. This is only written to disk when you flush it, you write a /n character or you fill the buffer up.

So in the first case, your file contains nothing when you come to read from it.

Comment: But it still does not work even if I use "test\n" instead of "test".

Comment: The answer is wrong in this regard: Writing `\n` to the file has no effect at all; you must flush the file or write so much data that the C library will flush by itself (usually 4KiB).

Comment: I think the \n bit depends on the implementation - MS does, at least for C++ code.