# fwrite() does not override text in Windows (C)

Tags: c, file-io, fwrite

I write this C code so that I could test whether fwrite could update some values in a text file. I tested on Linux and it works fine. In Windows (vista 32bits), however, it simply does not work. The file remains unchanged after I write a different byte using: cont = fwrite(&newfield, sizeof(char), 1, fp);

The registers are written on the file using a "@" separator, in the format:

`Reg1FirstField@Reg1SecondField@Reg2FirstField@Reg2SecondField...`

The final file should be: `First@1@Second@9@Third@1@`

I also tried putc and fprintf, all with no result. Can someone please help me with this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct test {
char field1[20];
char field2;
} TEST;

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    TEST reg, regread;
    char regwrite[22];
    int i, cont, charwritten;

    fp=fopen("testupdate.txt","w+");

    strcpy(reg.field1,"First");
    reg.field2 = '1';
    sprintf(regwrite,"%s@%c@", reg.field1, reg.field2);
    cont = (int)strlen(regwrite);
    charwritten = fwrite(regwrite,cont,1,fp);
    fflush(fp);

    strcpy(reg.field1,"Second");
    reg.field2 = '1';
    sprintf(regwrite,"%s@%c@", reg.field1, reg.field2);
    cont = (int)strlen(regwrite);
    charwritten = fwrite(regwrite,cont,1,fp);
    fflush(fp);

    strcpy(reg.field1,"Third");
    reg.field2 = '1';
    sprintf(regwrite,"%s@%c@", reg.field1, reg.field2);
    cont = (int)strlen(regwrite);
    charwritten = fwrite(regwrite,cont,1,fp);
    fflush(fp);
    fclose(fp);

    // open file to update
    fp=fopen("testupdate.txt","r+");

    printf("\nUpdate field 2 on the second register:\n");
    char aux[22];
    // search for second register and update field 2
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
       fscanf(fp,"%22[^@]@", aux);
       printf("%d-1: %s\n", i, aux);
       if (strcmp(aux, "Second") == 0) {
            char newfield = '9';
            cont = fwrite(&newfield, sizeof(char), 1, fp);
            printf("written: %d bytes, char: %c\n", cont, newfield);
            // goes back one byte in order to read properly 
            // on the next fscanf
            fseek(fp,-1,SEEK_CUR);
        } 
        fscanf(fp,"%22[^@]@", aux);
        printf("%d-2: %s\n",i, aux);
        aux[0] = '\0';
}
fflush(fp);
fclose(fp);

// open file to see if the update was made
fp=fopen("testupdate.txt","r");
for (i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
   fscanf(fp,"%22[^@]@", aux);
   printf("%d-1: %s\n", i, aux);
   fscanf(fp,"%22[^@]@",aux);
   printf("%d-2: %s\n",i, aux);
   aux[0] = '\0';
}
fclose(fp);
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `aux` has space for **21** "regular" characters and the null terminator. The conversion specification in `scanf` should be `%21[^@]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a file positioning function between the read and write. [The Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says:

> 7.19.5.3/6
>
> When a file is opened with  update  mode, both input and  output  may  be  performed  on  the associated  stream. However, ... input shall  not  be  directly  followed  by output  without  an  intervening  call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file. ...

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
   fscanf(fp,"%22[^@]@", aux);                              /* read */
   printf("%d-1: %s\n", i, aux);
   if (strcmp(aux, "Second") == 0) {
        char newfield = '9';

        /* added a file positioning function */
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);                             /* don't move */

        cont = fwrite(&newfield, sizeof(char), 1, fp);      /* write */
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't know it but here they explain it:
[why fseek or fflush is always required between reading and writing in the read/write "+" modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713819/why-fseek-or-fflush-is-always-required-between-reading-and-writing-in-the-read-wr)

Conclusion: You must either `fflush` or `fseek` before every write when you use `"+"`.

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);
// or
fflush(fp);

cont = fwrite(&newfield, sizeof(char), 1, fp);
```

Fix verified on Cygwin.

Comment: Apparently if you read, then write, you need to use a file-positioning function specifically, not just one or the other. It's only for write-then-read that `fflush()` can be used instead.

Comment: The buffering by the stream functions must be why the calls to `fgetpos` and `fsetpos` also worked in my updated answer below ...

Comment: Well, thank you @Jason, @LatinSud and @pmg for aswering my question! I've learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking any return values for errors. I'm guessing the file is read-only and is not even opening properly.

Comment: The file was written correctly, it just does not overwrite the value '1' with the value '9'. Also, I checked and the file was not saved with read-only permission.

Answer (score 0):

At least here on OSX, your value `9` is begin appended to the end of the file ... so you're not updating the actual register value for `Second` at it's position in the file.  For some reason after the scan for the appropriate point to modify the values, your stream pointer is actually at the end of the file.  For instance, running and compiling your code on OSX produced the following output in the actual text file:

```
First@1@Second@1@Third@1@9
```

The reason your initial read-back is working is because the data is being written, but it's at the end of the file. So when you write the value and then back-up the stream and re-read the value, that works, but it's not being written in the location you're assuming.

**Update:** I've added some calls to `ftell` to see what's happening to the stream pointer, and it seems that your calls to `fscanf` are working as you'd assume, but the call to `fwrite` is jumping to the end of the file.  Here's the modified output:

```
Update field 2 on the second register:
**Stream position: 0
0-1: First
0-2: 1
**Stream position: 8
1-1: Second
**Stream position before write: 15
**Stream position after write: 26
written: 1 bytes, char: 9
1-2: 9
**Stream position after read-back: 26
```

**Update-2:**  It seems by simply saving the position of the stream-pointer, and then setting the position of the stream-pointer, the call to 'fwrite` worked without skipping to the end of the file.  So I added:

```
fpos_t position;
fgetpos(fp, &position);
fsetpos(fp, &position);
```

right before the call to `fwrite`.  Again, this is on OSX, you may see something different on Windows.

Comment: The file pointer is in the write spot. I know it because if I substitute the line: `cont = fwrite(&newfield, sizeof(char), 1, fp);` by the line `fscanf(fp,"%c", &newfield);`, it reads exactly the '1' character I want to overwrite. Here in Linux the final text file is: `First@1@Second@9@Third@1@`, but in Windows is `First@1@Second@1@Third@1@`. Thanks anyway for your contribution.

Comment: Yes, you're stream pointer is in the correct spot *before* the write, but not after the write ... at least not on OSX.  For some reason it seems to be treating the "r+" flag like an "a+" flag for the call to `fopen`.  Obviously there are some odd platform-variations happening here.

Answer (score -2):

With this:

```
fp=fopen("testupdate.txt","w+");
                            ^------ Notice the + sign
```

You opened the file in "append" mode -- that is what the plus sign does in this parameter.  As a result, all of your `fwrite()` calls will be relative to the end of the file.

Using `"r+"` for the `fopen()` mode doesn't make sense -- the `+` means nothing in this case.

This and other issues with `fopen()` are why I prefer to use the POSIX-defined `open()`.

To fix your particular case, get rid of the `+` characters from the `fopen()` modes, and consider that you might need to specify binary format on Windows (`"wb"` and `"rb"` modes).

Comment: No, `a` or `a+` would be appending to the end of the file. `w+` means reading+writing, but overwriting an existing file. And `r+` indicates both reading and writing without any clearing of the original file.