# Is a sync/flush needed before writes to a locked file from multiple threads/processes in fopen a+ mode?

Tags: c, file, concurrency, locking, fopen

I'm performing I/O to a single file from multiple threads.  Access to this shared file `foo` is controlled through an advisory file lock (`flock(2)` with `LOCK_EX`).  `foo` was opened with `fopen(3)` mode `a+`.  `a+` was chosen because of the documentation stating:

> Subsequent writes to the file will always end up at the then current
>   end of file, irrespective of any intervening `fseek(3)` or similar.

Simplified, the operations would start:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("foo", "a+");
...spawn threads...
```

Writing would continue:

```
flock(fileno(fp), LOCK_EX);
fwrite(buffer, buffer_size, 1, fp);
flock(fileno(fp), LOCK_UN);
```

I currently do not have any `fflush(3)` or `fsync(2)` calls before the `fwrite(3)` and am wondering if I should.  Does the `fopen(3)` `a+` mode take into account multiple threads hitting the file when calculating the "current EOF"?  I know that `flock(2)` likely has no problem granting me the lock while there is outstanding I/O.

In my limited tests (write very long lines of ASCII text followed by a newline in multiple threads for many seconds, then ensure the number of characters on each line in the resulting file are equal), I have not seen any "corruption" when not using `fflush(3)` or `fsync(2)`.  Their presence greatly decreases I/O performance.

tl;dr:
When using file locks, do I need to flush the stream before writing to a shared file between multiple threads with opened in `a+` mode?  Multiple forks/different machines writing to a file a parallel file system?

Possibly related:
[why fseek or fflush is always required between reading and writing in the read/write "+" modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713819/why-fseek-or-fflush-is-always-required-between-reading-and-writing-in-the-read-w)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the wrong kind of lock.  `flock` is *only* for locking between processes, not between threads in the same process.  From `man 2 flock`:

```
A call to flock() may block if an incompatible lock is held by  another
process.   To  make  a  nonblocking request, include LOCK_NB (by ORing)
with any of the above operations.
```

Emphasis added.  And...

```
A process may only hold one type of lock (shared  or  exclusive)  on  a
file.   Subsequent flock() calls on an already locked file will convert
an existing lock to the new lock mode.
```

You want to use `flockfile` instead (or additionally, if using multiple processes as well).  The `flockfile` function which is used for controlling access to a `FILE *` from multiple threads.  From the man page:

```
The stdio functions are thread-safe.  This is achieved by assigning  to
each  FILE object a lockcount and (if the lockcount is nonzero) an own‐
ing thread.  For each library call, these functions wait until the FILE
object  is no longer locked by a different thread, then lock it, do the
requested I/O, and unlock the object again.

(Note: this locking has nothing to do with the  file  locking  done  by
functions like flock(2) and lockf(3).)
```

Like this:

```
// in one of the threads...
flockfile(fp);
fwrite(..., fp);
funlockfile(fp);
```

The good news is that on `glibc`, you don't need to lock the file if you only have one function call from stdio.h in each critical section, since `glibc` has a `fwrite` that locks.  But this is not true across other platforms, and it certainly doesn't hurt to lock the file.  So if you are running on Linux, you never would have noticed that `flock` doesn't do what you want, since `fwrite` does it automatically.

**About append mode:** You do not need extra flushes when writing using append mode, unless you want to ensure ordering between different processes that have the same file open (or one process with multiple handles for the same file).  You do not need "a+" mode unless you are reading from the file.

### Demonstration of `flock`

If you don't believe me that `flock` does NOT provide thread safety between threads using the same file descriptor, here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/file.h>

static FILE *fp;
static pthread_mutex_t mutex;
static pthread_cond_t cond;
int state;

static void fail_func(int code, const char *func, int line)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: error: %s\n", func, line, strerror(code));
    exit(1);
}

#define fail(code) fail_func(code, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__)

void *thread1(void *p)
{
    int r;

    // Lock file (thread 2 does not have lock yet)
    r = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (r) fail(r);
    r = flock(fileno(fp), LOCK_EX);
    if (r) fail(errno);
    puts("thread1: flock successful");
    state = 1;
    r = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    if (r) fail(r);

    // Wake thread 2
    r = pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    if (r) fail(r);

    // Wait for thread 2
    r = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (r) fail(r);
    while (state != 2) {
        r = pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        if (r) fail(r);
    }
    puts("thread1: exiting");
    r = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    if (r) fail(r);

    return NULL;
}

void *thread2(void *p)
{
    int r;

    // Wait for thread 1
    r = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (r) fail(r);
    while (state != 1) {
        r = pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        if (r) fail(r);
    }

    // Also lock file (thread 1 already has lock)
    r = flock(fileno(fp), LOCK_EX);
    if (r) fail(r);
    puts("thread2: flock successful");

    // Wake thread 1
    state = 2;
    puts("thread2: exiting");
    r = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    if (r) fail(r);
    r = pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    if (r) fail(r);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t t1, t2;
    void *ret;
    int r;

    r = pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    if (r) fail(r);
    r = pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);
    if (r) fail(r);
    fp = fopen("flockfile.txt", "a");
    if (!fp) fail(errno);
    r = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, thread1, NULL);
    if (r) fail(r);
    r = pthread_create(&t2, NULL, thread2, NULL);
    if (r) fail(r);
    r = pthread_join(t1, &ret);
    if (r) fail(r);
    r = pthread_join(t2, &ret);
    if (r) fail(r);
    puts("done");
    return 0;
}
```

On my system, it produces the following output:

```
thread1: flock successful
thread2: flock successful
thread2: exiting
thread1: exiting
done
```

Note that thread 1 does not release the `flock`, and thread 2 is able to acquire it anyway.  The use of a condition variable ensures that thread 1 does not exit until thread 2 has acquired the lock.  **This is exactly what the `flock` man page says,** because `flock` says that the locks are per-file and per-process but NOT per-thread.

### Summary for atomically appending to a file

In order to make an atomic write between processes and threads, you can do one of two easy things:

- Use `write` and write no more than `PIPE_BUF` bytes.  `PIPE_BUF` is defined in `<limits.h>`, on my system it is 4096.  If the file descriptor is open in `O_APPEND` mode, then the write will go atomically to the end of the file, no matter who else is writing to the file (threads and/or processes).
- Use `write` and `flock`.  If you *ever* write more than `PIPE_BUF` bytes at a time, this is your only option for all writes.  Again, if the file is open in `O_APPEND` mode, then the bytes will go to the end of the file.  This will happen atomically, but only from the perspective of everyone with an `flock`.

Additionally,

- If you use `<stdio.h>` and share a `FILE *` between threads, you will also need to call `flockfile` from each thread.  This is not needed if you use the lower-level POSIX API (`open`/`write`/etc).  This is also not needed if you use `glibc` and every write is a single function call (e.g., you want to atomically `fputs`).
- If you use only one process, `flock` is not needed.

Comment: I think you're reading into the warning in the man page for `flock` too much.  Even after re-reading it, I content that `flock` works fine between threads.  In addition, `flockfile` would not work between multiple processes, since the lock is on the `FILE*` and not the file itself.

Comment: As for append mode (the original question), I don't necessarily need to ensure the order in which processes write, but I absolutely cannot have one process writing at what it thinks is the EOF, but the EOF has changed because another thread/process has extended the file since the last I/O.

Comment: @greg: I have added a demonstration that `flock` does not do what you want.  Feel free to run it on your computer.  I think append mode does what you want.  You may wish to use POSIX file descriptors, since it looks like the buffer provided by `stdio` is just getting in your way.  Read the man page `man 2 open` and look at the description of `O_APPEND`, which is what what `fopen` uses for both `a` and `a+` mode.

Comment: @greg: As for `flockfile`, yes I am aware that `flockfile` is per-thread but does not lock across processes.  Since you did not mention processes in your post, I did not cover it.  In order to lock between threads and processes you will need to use both `flockfile` and `flock`.  Using only one of them will not work.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll need to evaluate how I'm "getting lucky" in my test case threads using only `flock`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is not quite right.

1. write() to a file with append mode is atomic between multi-threads and multi-process, no matter how much bytes is written in one time. See the standard : http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html 
   **If the O_APPEND flag of the file status flags is set, the file offset shall be set to the end of the file prior to each write and no intervening file modification operation shall occur between changing the file offset and the write operation.**
2. if write() to a FIFO or pipe with append mode, the PIPE_BUF limits the max size of atomic write.
3. the stdio library do not guarantee multi-process or multi-threads atomic append write. As each FILE* has its own buffer.
4. flockfile works just when 1. Only one process operates the file 2. multi-threads write the file with one FILE*.
5. So, when multi-process or multi-threads need to write file with stdio functions, using advisory lock is the only choice, flock only works under linux, using fcntl is portable.