# Getting a black image when trying to convert .bmp to grayscale

Tags: c, file, fread, bmp, fseek

For every pixel in bmp, I tried to change its blue, green, and red color though some sort of calculation. But it gave me an image that's entirely black.

The following is part of my code in main():

```
fseek(bmpfile, offset, SEEK_SET);
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){  //loop for every row
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){    //loop for every pixel in every row
        Pixel p; //Pixel is a construct that has 3 char fields of b, g, r.
        fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, file);
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "-g") == 0){
            float b1 = p.b/255;
            float g1 = p.g/255;
            float r1 = p.r/255;     

            float gr = 0.2 * r1 + 0.7 * g1 + 0.07* b1;
            if (gr <= 0.003){
                gr = 13*gr;                 
            }else{
                gr = (1.1*pow(gr,1/2.4)-1);     
            }
            p.b = (char)(gr*255);
            p.g = (char)(gr*255);
            p.r = (char)(gr*255);

        }
        fseek(bmpfile, -(sizeof(p)), SEEK_CUR); 
        fwrite(&p, sizeof(p), 1, bmpfile);
    }   
    fseek (bmpfile, padding, SEEK_CUR);
```

Comment: "3 char fields of b, g, r" - if they really are `char`, then `p.b/255` will be zero  in all but potentially one case due to integer division. The same is true for the other two (g and r). Divide by `255.0f` instead.

Comment: I just edited my code strcmp(argv[1], "-g") == 0; This helped to solve the black image. But now the program makes no change on my bmpfile at all. I tried to use 255.0f for calculating b1, g1, and r1 but it still keeps giving me the image without any color change.

Comment: How you get 10?

Comment: Are the three `char` members signed or unsigned?

Comment: It's actually smaller than that. Put in the value 255 for `p.b`, `p.g`, and `p.r` and do the calculation by hand.

Comment: In `fread(&pixel, sizeof(p), 1, file);` what is `pixel`? You go on to use `p` in `float b1 = p.b/255;` etc.

Comment: I simply declared them as char. So I guess they are signed.

Comment: So if the colour level is 255, that will come out as -1. I suggest you make them `unsigned char`.

Comment: Yes that should be &p. I modified my code a little bit before putting it here. Sorry about that. Just edited it.

Comment: Re the edit: this is one reason why the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is requested, so the code really is your code!

Comment: After changing `strcmp(argv[1], "-g")==0)`, you need to give `-g` as the first argument to the program. Otherwise, none of the grayscale code runs.

Comment: On an unrelated note, your code has undefined behavior. The loop does `fread`, `fseek`, `fwrite`, and then goes back to the `fread`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228509/function-for-bmp-color-inverting-doesnt-work) for an explanation of why that's bad.

Comment: OT: `uint32_t int gr = 200U * p.r + 700U * p.g + 70U * p.b; if(gr <= 765) { gr = gr * 13U / 1000; } else { gr = pow(gr/255000.0)*255 }` avoids most of this floating point stuff... By adding 500 before division or 0.5 before asignment respectively, you additionally round commercially.

Comment: Do you mean like putting "-g" after the filename?

Comment: No, I mean that `-g` needs to be in `argv[1]`, so the first thing on the command line after the program name.

Comment: @user3386109 You're right. I wrongly put "--g" in garv[1]. It works now!