# fgets seems to cause write to file

Tags: c

I ran the following test after trying to help someone with a piece of Python code; I know the test is simple but I can't figure out why this happens.

The basic idea is this: I have the following C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *pf = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
    char buf[100];
    fgets(buf, 100, pf);
    fseek(pf, -7, SEEK_CUR);
    fwrite("0", 1, 1, pf);
    //NEXT LINE PROBLEMATIC
    fgets(buf, 100, pf);
    fclose(pf);
    return 0;
}
```

and the input file containing one line:
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

I would expect the output to contain a zero inside the string; however, this happens:
abcdefghijklmnopqrs0bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

(there are multiple space characters after the text). If I comment out the problematic line (the second call to fgets), the output works as expected.

Does anybody have any idea why that happens?

To me it seemed like a buffer overflow because of the space characters after the end of the line; reproducing using cl.exe instead of gcc I get this:
abcdefghijklmnopqrs0bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzt e s t e \ p y _ w e i r d \ t e s t . t x t   c l e  ;i  À ] h&^ u a

So it's definitely an overflow caused, most likely, by interweaving calls to fgets with calls to fseek/fwrite.

Comment: I suspect it's a problem with buffered IO.  Use `fflush(pf)` after `fwrite()`.

Comment: EOF, you're right, adding the `fflush` right after `fwrite()` makes it work correctly. Still, the buffer is small, I don't understand what goes on underneath.

Comment: The buffer is invisible to you.  It is likely 4K.

Comment: It will be good to add error checking code around `fwrite` and `fgets` to make sure that the code does what you expect it to.

Comment: n.m., thanks for the reference, I didn't find that one when looking. I've just read it and, as I assumed, it's a buffering problem but I can't get it. The thing is, this comes from a piece of Python code calling fgets!

Comment: @stark, I was referring to my own, temporary buffer `buf[100]`.

Comment: What output are you talking about ? There is no output in your program.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody finds this, n.m.'s suggestion is correct, I don't know why I couldn't find it when I first search. See the answer here: [why fseek or fflush is always required between reading and writing in the read/write "+" modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713819/why-fseek-or-fflush-is-always-required-between-reading-and-writing-in-the-read-w)

Someone with more reputation, please mark as a duplicate and close :)

Comment: Marked as a duplicate and closed as requested.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing surnatural...

This reads the 26 alphabetic chars and the current offset will be set to 26:

```
fgets(buf, 100, pf);
```

This sets the current offset to 19, so pointing to the 20th char of the alphabet `t`:

```
fseek(pf, -7, SEEK_CUR);
```

Then this writes `0` over `t` and set the offset to 20:

```
fwrite("0", 1, 1, pf);
```

This reads the remaining chars `uvwxyz` in buf and set the offset to 26:
    fgets(buf, 100, pf);

So at the end you will have `abcdefghijklmnopqrs0uvwxyz` in the file.

What's in the buffer is the content of the last read, which is necessarily `uvwxyz` (the six last chars of the file, no doubt) as nothing was done to modify them and there is only one offset per open file.